# How to echo names in PHP/HTML listed by group/rank

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

I'm making a NASCAR league for my family, and I'm working on a roster page so they can add or remove drivers. How do I list the drivers from the rank they're in which can be found in the database? (A/B/C/D/E groups)

This is for my website's roster page, I've tried to look for the group they were in from their database group.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-4" style="margin: 0px auto;float: none;">
<div class="card">
<div class="card-body">
<font style="font-size: 18px;">Add/Remove Drivers</font>
<div style="height:10px"></div>
<center><strong>Rank A</strong></center>

 </div>
</div>
```

I want Rank A to show the drivers in Rank A which is sorted like the picture linked. And then, b, c, d, e and so on.
https://gyazo.com/8c5c987c9dc7202ff90913f1125057ce

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried? What is your error?

Comment: Well, I can't figure out how to echo it. @Jaquarh

Comment: `echo` and your variable maybe? Without your code, how can we answer this? If your query brings back an ASSOC array, use `$yourResultsVariable['your_column']`, if its an object, `$yourResultsVariable->your_column`

Comment: `GROUP` is a MySQL reserved word, I hope you know this and how it should be handled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can output your data.

```
$stmt = (new PDO('dsn here', 'username', 'password', [
            PDO::EMULATE_PREPARES => false
        ]))->Prepare('SELECT * FROM yourTable WHERE `group` = ?');

$stmt->execute(array('B'), PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($stmt->fetchAll() as $row) {
    echo $row['driver_name']; # Kurt Busch
}
```

Here, each result is returned as an associative array when we execute `\PDOResult::fetchAll`. The keys of the multidimensional array hold your column names.

Comment: You should note that `GROUP` is a MySQL reserved word and that it requires it to be encapsulated in ticks and should be edited.

Comment: That is a well noted point, didn't even cross my mind. I'll update the answer @FunkFortyNiner